# Android GStreamer mp4 file error

Tags: android, media-player, gstreamer

I am using Eclipse juno on windows platform. I configured gstreamer in eclipse. I downloaded gstreamer from [here](http://docs.gstreamer.com/display/GstSDK/Installing+for+Android+development).

I am working on the tutorial 5 that is given in the gst-sdk folder. When I try to play mp4 file, I get the error:

```
amcvideodec-omxgoogleh264decoder Internal data stream error
```

I have checked the plugins.mk file and it contains all the required plugins needed to play mp4 file. I want to execute any transport stream file. But even a mp4 file is not getting played. Help needed.

Comment: What platform are you running this on? Is this running directly on an Android device? Or on an emulator?

Comment: I am running it on android 4.2. And I am using emulator. Actually, I somehow managed to remove this error. I enabled the option **use host gpu** in create a new avd device, and it started working properly. Now the problem is in some mp4 files, I am able to hear the sound but no video is displayed. While in others, video is displayed but audio  cant be heard. Do you have any idea what problem might have occured?

Comment: We need to know more details about what is in the MP4 files since not all MP4 files are created equally. Use ffprobe (part of FFmpeg) or MediaInfo to identify. Figure out what audio and video codecs are inside the MP4 files.

Comment: I found out the codecs. However, when I try to play any transport stream file, I get the message, **Your GStreamer installation is missing a plugin** I checked my plugin.mk file, but there is already a mpegts plugin in the codec field. After searching on internet, I came across the gst-good plugin. But I dont know how to configure it in eclipse. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Are you certain that you are playing a transport stream file? Your comments up to this point indicate that you have been playing MP4 files.